# Inject DB Instance For Static and Instance Accessibility

Tags: java, gwt, dependency-injection, guice, requestfactory

I have a POJO that is used with GWT's RequestFactory and an associated proxy. The POJO has both static methods (`list()`) and instance methods (`persist()`) which need access to my database. My database connection pool is set up to be injected as a singleton via Guice. What I am unsure of is how exactly can I perform the injection so that both of these types of methods can access it?

Furthermore, the instances of the POJO are created using an empty constructor, thus negating the ability to use constructor injection.

Here's a sample POJO for reference's sake:

```
public class Person {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public Integer getId() { return this.id; }
    public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }
    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public void persist() {
        //TODO: save state to DB
    }
    public static List<Person> list() {
        //TODO: get all people from DB
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're wanting to use dependency injection shouldn't you have a dependency on the singleton so it can be injected? Ie pass it into the constructor of the Object. The empty constructor can't be used in that case is my understanding.

Comment: I do not have control over which constructor is called. I should have made that more clear. The RequestFactory framework automatically calls the default constructor and setXXX methods to build the POJO. It will error if there is no default constructor visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow, GWT's style is still not very aware of the needs of dependency injection. This is - to some extent - excusable on the client side, but not so much on the server side (and to be honest, I'd really wish, that the GWT and Guice team will join forces to improve this situation.)

Now, fortunately, Guice provides a "legacy" mechanism for injecting static fields, see "Static injections" in http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=google-guice&s=google-guice&t=Injections). So you can inject your EntityManager/EntityManagerFactory (or whatever you're using to perform persistence) into a static field.

You don't have to do that directly, but you can use a Provider. Then choose the correct scope (e.g. @RequestScoped) to make the provider give you the correct instance.

*Note:* I haven't tried that yet (though I'm planning to do so), because I'm not yet using RequestFactory in a real project. I hope that the legacy mechanism works in this case, but you may hit some roadblocks (?)

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't think of this but it works perfectly. My module creates an eager singleton of the connection pool provider and then static injects it into the factory which allows for static access from anywhere. Definitely not the best solution but it will work well enough. Hopefully GWT's RequestFactory is made aware of injectable constructors in future versions so this can be avoided. Also, I've just seen 2.1.1 allows for chainable service decorators which (apparently) allow you to perform custom actions (e.g., Guice instantiation).

Answer (score 2):

The pojo doesn't have to be default-instantiable if you use a [Locator](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/requestfactory/shared/Locator.html) to control how the RequestFactory server code obtains instances of your POJOs by implementing `Locator.find()` as appropriate for your domain object. Locators also allow you use domain objects that don't conform to the `getId() / getVersion()` protocol.

```
@ProxyFor(value = Person.class, locator = PersonLocator.class)
interface PersonProxy extends EntityProxy { .... }
```

If you need to alter the behavior for most of your domain pojos, you can inject a [ServiceLayerDecorator](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/requestfactory/server/ServiceLayerDecorator.html) that overloads `createDomainObject()` and `loadDomainObject()`.

Comment: This is definitely a good way to go if you need more customized instantiations. I was going to use this method for Guice instantiation but I realized that since I was already serving the `/gwtRequest` URL with a Guice binding it would also automatically use Guice for instantiation thereby allowing `@Inject` constructors. https://github.com/JakeWharton/GwtBase/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/gwtbase/guice/GuiceServletModule.java